# is this a safe way to use SELECT via PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)
>   [How do I sanitize input with PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364686/how-do-i-sanitize-input-with-pdo)

I'm pulling in an id via `$_GET`. I just started using PDO and I'm unsure if this is safe or not. Obviously, the code below is using `$_GET` to grab an id. I'm not sanitizing it at all before I place it in the query. Is this safe?

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$blogid = $_GET['id'];
$post = $dbh->query("SELECT id, title, slug, body, image, author, date, category from   blog WHERE id='$blogid' ORDER BY date DESC");
$row = $post->fetch(); ?>
```

Comment: Why are people so down-vote happy on this site? :) Geez...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sanitizing it at all before I place it in the query

Nope.  Not safe at all.  :)

You either need to escape it, or use a prepared statement.  With PDO, I would use a prepared statement:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_string($_GET['id'])) {
    $blogid = $_GET['id'];
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, title, slug, body, image, author, date, category from   blog WHERE id= :id ORDER BY date DESC");
    $stmt->execute(array('id' => $_GET['id']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Comment: ok, I misunderstood how PDO handled this. I thought `$post = $dbh->query` would sanitize this.

Comment: How would it do that?  That would be some quite painful string manipulation.  query() just sends the literal query with no processing of any kind (essentially) to the server.

Comment: Don't know, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is **NEVER** safe to insert a variable in a SQL query without sanitizing/escaping it.

What you could do, if you don't want to escape it yourself is to use a `prepare` statement and  `bind` your parameters.

You can check the PHP documentation...

About of how use PDO prepare:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

How to use the parameters binding:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php