# MySQL query not executing properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to make a PHP login script, that when user signs in, it removes the Sign-In form with another div saying "Welcome [user_name]". I am running the script on same page as my html, but the query always fails. Can anyone please sort out this problem, why is this happening?

PHP CODE:

```
<?php include("connect.php")?>
<?php
    session_start();

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['username'])){

        //Sanitize the POST values
        $UserName = clean($_POST['username']);
        $Password =(md5($_POST['password']));

        //Create query
        $qry = "SELECT 'UserName' , 'Password' FROM users WHERE UserName='$UserName' AND Password='$Password'";
        $result = mysql_query($qry);

        //Check whether the query was successful or not
        if($result) {
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                //Login Successful
                session_regenerate_id();
                $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['mem_id'];
                $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['FName'];
                $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['LName'];
                //session_write_close();
                echo 'SUCCESS';
                //loggedin();
                //exit();
            }
            else {
                //Login failed
                echo 'FAILED.';
                //loginfail();
                //exit();
                }
            }
        else {
            die("Query failed");
        }   
    }
?>
```

HTML CODE:

```
<form name="user-form" id="user-form" action="members.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username"></input>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"></input>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" id="sign" name="Sign In"></input>
                </form>
```

Your help will be appreciated as I am new to this.

Comment: remove all the single quotes from the column names. `SELECT 'UserName' , 'Password'` should be `SELECT UserName , Password`

Comment: You should Bind Variables, not sanatize, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364686/how-do-i-sanitize-input-with-pdo

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty is correct, you can switch them to ``` backticks if you prefer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a helpdesk where we "sort out this problem" for you.

Comment: Does your `html` and `php` scripts are in the same `members.php`. If it is, you need to check whether the `$_POST` request called.

Comment: Another remark: Please do *not* use md5 for hashing the password. md5 is broken. Additionally these hash algorithms are designed to run fast, which means brute force attacks are more likely to succeed if your database gets compromised. You should use bcrypt (or similar). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php

Comment: Please be aware that the mysql extension (supplying the mysql_ functions) has been deprecated since 2012, in favor of the mysqli and PDO extensions. It's use is highly discouraged. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong-

```
SELECT 'UserName' , 'Password'....
```

remove `'` and replace with

Also take care of the strings properly, just replace `WHERE UserName='$UserName' AND Password='$Password'"` with-

```
WHERE UserName=\"".$UserName."\" AND Password=\"".$Password."\""
```

So the complete query would be-

```
 "SELECT `UserName` , `Password` FROM users WHERE UserName=\"".$UserName."\" AND Password=\"".$Password."\""
```

(also keep in mind that the column names are case-sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$qry = "SELECT 'UserName' , 'Password' FROM users WHERE UserName='$UserName' AND Password='$Password'";
```

Should be:

```
$qry = "SELECT username , password FROM users WHERE UserName='$UserName' AND Password='$Password'";
```

Comment: Well, no, you _should_ delimit the column names. But you should do it properly, which means backticks and not single quotes.

Comment: In 12 years of programming I've never worked for a company with standards that involved delimiting column names. This should only ever be necessary if a column name is a reserved word in the SQL database you are using, in which case you should probably be renaming columns.

Comment: That's fine. But you should point out the bugs which is asked by the questionnaire. This `.....` should be `......`. It's not clearly guide the user. You need to answer make sensible. [Read out here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Mark: Then you've worked for companies with some pretty awful coding standards, IMO. In 20 years of programming I've never worked for a company which would promote such sloppiness and lack of rigour.

Comment: I disagree entirely. Coding standards are guidelines at best, and opinion at worst. In this particular case, though, backtick support for column identifiers varies depending on the environment and the environment settings. Developing without them leaves the code flexible enough to support multiple environments without needing substantial modifications, and developing code like that should be habit to allow a developer to more fluidly move between environments. But, that too, is just my opinion.